# Valgrind results clean but with more allocs than frees

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, heap-memory, valgrind

Im getting this result from Valgrind:

```
    ==24810== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==24810==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==24810==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 6 frees, 0 bytes allocated
    ==24810== 
    ==24810== LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==24810==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==24810==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==24810==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==24810==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==24810==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

It says no memory was leaked. It looks to me as a good result. But, what about these *9 allocs, 6 frees*? It looks like I haven't free'd some memory somewhere. I checked the code, and there are 3 global const pointers. Maybe they weren't considered as errors but printed as not free'd?

Should I worry about this or should I considered the code buggless?
Thank you all.
....Just trying to understand all that ANSI C hassle with pointers and memory allocations :)))

maxim

Comment: It says that total heap usage is `0 bytes allocated`, could they be empty allocations? Can you post some code?

Comment: Does valgrind count `realloc`s?

Comment: @Nick Nah, that would still result in non-0 lost blocks.

Comment: g++ on Linux Ubuntu 10. Valgrind actuaslly only works with gcc&family on Linux

Comment: Well, if valgrind counts `realloc`s, there could be 3 `realloc`s with non-`NULL` pointer argument among the 9 `alloc`s, so it all adds up. What about checking the source?

Comment: the source is clean. No segfaults. The only thing there is const char * declared 3 times in global scope, which makes me think is the actual reason for Valgrind to count them as allocated and not free'd. Now I cannot test it by freeing, it on production server right now. I will try tomorrow locally and give you here an update

Comment: @DanielFischer A realloc() is counted as an alloc and a free by valgrind, so it can't be that.  And, those global const char*s are not allocated on the heap, so those aren't it either.  What a weird one!

Comment: Normally Valgrind comes with a list of stuff in system libraries to ignore. It's possible that the system libraries allocate 3 things and never free them, but valgrind knows this is not your program's fault. Also note that not freeing "always in use" things immediately before terminating the process (and therefore avoiding a little overhead) is a valid optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in valgrind website http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.interpret

> "definitely lost": your program is leaking memory -- fix it!
>
> "probably lost": your program is leaking memory, unless you're doing
>   funny things with pointers (such as moving them to point to the middle
>   of a heap block).

So for your case your program should be good.